# How do I load a custom bundle in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In Objective-C I was doing this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LUIImages" ofType:@"bundle"];
path = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] pathForResource:_imageHash ofType:nil];
```

But I can't seem to find equivalent in swift 3

```
let bundlePath: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "LiveUI", ofType: "bundle")!
```

But what is the next step? Or is there any better way to load a custom bundle?

Comment: `Bundle(path: "...")?.path(forResource: "...", ofType: "...")` ? – Just try the autocompletion, it should guide you.

Comment: ha, I have used init but this works too obviously ... would you like to turn this into an answer so I can confirm it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `Bundle(path:)` constructor and avoid forced unwrapping:

```
if let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "LiveUI", ofType: "bundle"),
    let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath),
    let path = bundle.path(forResource: "...", ofType: nil) {
    print(path)
} else {
    print("not found")
}
```

An alternative is to load the bundle using the bundle identifier
(defined in the bundle's Info.plist):

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.company.bundle.LiveUI")
```

Comment: How can we register custom bundle in plist?